# Creating a method in objective-c with a delay argument

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimeinterval

I'm trying to create a method with an argument in objective-c, the argument is an amount of seconds before the actual method starts.

I'm trying to avoid using the `[self performSelector:(SEL) withObject:(id) afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)];` because having the delay within my method would actually save me a lot of coding as I am planning to add other arguments to this method.

Example of the method:

```
-(void) startMethodAfterArgumentDelay: (NSTimeInterval *)delay{
     NSLog(@"perform action after argument delay");
}
```

and how to call it:

```
[self startMethodAfterArgumentDelay:3.0f];
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use any 3rd party libraries as the other answer suggested, this is easy enough to implement yourself using GCD's [dispatch_after()](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_after). Just note that this method is a asynchronous, so your method will return immediately even though the contents of the block are delayed.

```
- (void)startMethodAfterArgumentDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay
{
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delay * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"perform action after argument delay");
    });
}
```

Comment: Brilliant!! After I changed NSTimeInterval to a float, this worked flawlessly! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use [BlocksKit](https://github.com/zwaldowski/BlocksKit) and then write code like that:

```
[self bk_performBlock:^(id obj) {
    //code
} afterDelay:delay];
```

Answer (score 1):

Just feed `delay` to `dispatch_after`.

```
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delay * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
    // do whatever
});
```